# How to disable Overriding Razor class library views

Tags: asp.net-core, view, overriding, disable, razor-class-library

I am now using ASP.Net Core to write a web application and relative Razor Class Libraries.
I know a view (*.cshtml) defined in a Razor Class Library can be override in web application. It brings enough flexibility to developers. But I feel sometimes the developer of a RCL doesn't expect that the view defined in RCL would be override.

Is there a way to disable overriding view (all or some specific views)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't achieve this. The project will auto override the view. The [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) has explian this.

> When a view, partial view, or Razor Page is found in both the web app
> and the RCL, the Razor markup (.cshtml file) in the web app takes
> precedence.

> When a view, partial view, or Razor Page is found in both the web app
> and the RCL, the Razor markup (.cshtml file) in the web app takes
> precedence. For example, add
> WebApp1/Areas/MyFeature/Pages/Page1.cshtml to WebApp1, and Page1 in
> the WebApp1 will take precedence over Page1 in the RCL.